# How to mention a user in a command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I don't know how to make a command to interact with a user by mentioning with this command structure

I know it is not possible as the command is currently

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "avatar",
    permission: "SEND_MESSAGES",
    async run(message) {
        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        const avatarEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();

        user
        avatarEmbed
            .setColor("FF0000")
            .setAuthor(message.author.username)
            .setImage(message.author.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }))


        message.channel.send({embeds: [avatarEmbed]});

    }
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "avatar",
    permission: "SEND_MESSAGES",
    async run(message) {
        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        const avatarEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();

        avatarEmbed
            .setColor("FF0000")
            .setAuthor(message.author.username)
            .setImage(message.author.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }))


        message.channel.send({ content: `<@${user.id}>`, embeds: [avatarEmbed]});

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the object directly and discord.js will manage it. Or you can go with the raw method

```
`<@{user.id}>`
```

```
`<@!{user.id}>`
```

or

```
`${user}` // discord.js will do the rest
```

But, either way, it will work